# A Kivy pixel measurement problem caused by Apple's Retina display

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, retina-display

## Problem

How to allow Kivy to use the same pixel measurement to create `Window` and `Screen` on devices with Retina display?

## Description

The pixel measurements for `Window` and `Screen` are not consistent on Apple's Retina display. The width and height of a `Window` are always twice as long as input values. It seems `Window` uses 1 logical pixel as 1 unit, and `Screen` and its children use 1 physical pixel as 1 unit

> Apple calls this mode HiDPI mode. In simpler words, it is one logical pixel = four physical pixels at the very beginning.   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_display).

### Example Code

- The following code creates a (500, 500)-size `Window` and a `Screen` with supposedly the same size. Inside this `Screen`, a `Button` on the top right corner and a 500-by-500 `Rectangle` are created. The `Button` shows the `Screen` size and other information when clicked.
- `main.py`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.metrics import Metrics

Config.set("graphics", "width", 500)
Config.set("graphics", "height", 500)

dpi_info = Metrics.dpi
pixel_density_info = Metrics.density

print("Before app starts, dpi is ", dpi_info)
print("Before app starts, pixel density is ", pixel_density_info)


class AppScreen(Screen):

    @staticmethod
    def show_metrics_data():
        print("when app is running, dpi is ", dpi_info)
        print("when app is running, pixel density is ", pixel_density_info)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        app_screen = AppScreen()
        return app_screen


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

- `main.kv`

```
<AppScreen>
    Button:
        on_press:
            print(root.size)
            root.show_metrics_data()
```

#### Results

- When the `Button`, which shows screen size, got pressed, it prints `[1000, 1000]` instead of `[500, 500]`.
- A 500-by-500 `Rectangle` only has half of the width and height comparing to the `Window` which configured also to be 500-by-500.
- Before app runs and when app is running, the same values for dpi and pixel density are returned, with dpi being 192.0 and pixel density being 2.0 for both cases.[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK2HR.png)

*edit*:

- When connect my current Retina-display device to a monitor which does not have a Retina display and set this monitor to **main screen**, everything is as expected when running the code. The sizes of `Screen`, `Window` and `Rectangle` are all 500-by-500 and `Rectangle` fills the whole `Screen` instead of just a part of it.[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU8qt.png)

*edit*:

- Interestingly enough, if I put the above result onto Retina display, it suddenly looks like this:[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mplDF.png)

## Possible reasons

Currently, the only possible reason I can think of for this is because `Window`'s size is created based on logical pixels and `Screen` adopts that created size. However, when creating widgets, executing canvas drawing instructions or retrieving `Screen` size values, somehow original size information is converted to physical-pixel based information.

Comment: When targeting different platforms its better to use `dp` for pixel dimensions. See [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.metrics.html#dimensions)...

Comment: It's basically essential that inside the app, physical pixels are used, otherwise it wouldn't be possible to address every pixel (as you might reasonably want to do). It's a mildly surprising API to have the Window use logical pixels, I'm not sure if there's a reason for this (like consistency with how other apps behave) or if it's just an artefact of of the window management API. In any case, the solution is probably to use `dp` to convert between physical and logical pixel sizes.

Comment: So after some research, my guess is that `Window` uses logical pixels or `dp` so it matches other applications' window sizes on a system; it is kind of like  `Window` uses the pixel measurement which is expected by the system. However, when drawing within the window (or app), the app take control of whatever is happening. So you can use different pixel measurements and physical pixel is just a default option. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Btw, `dp()` returns `float` not `int`.

 `dp` (density-independent pixel) and logical pixel are basically the same thing( research from the Internet, not guarantee to be true)